# Getting POP3-SSL using a POP3 client

Tags: email, pop3

We outsource our email using exchangemymail.com. They have POP3 access, but it requires SSL. Our CRM system has a mail sweeper that only supports regular POP3. How can I bridge the gap between secure and insecure POP3 so that I can sweep a mail account on our outsourced server using the CRM system?

Is there an app that can do this? Or is there a free email service out there that supports standard (insecure) POP3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) for Gmail's POP3S service, works like a charm. Here's a sample config:

```
# stunnel.conf
[pop3s]
accept  = LOCALPORT
connect = SECURESERVER:PORT
```

Then you point your CRM the LOCALPORT you define.

Comment: Is this the right way around?  stunnel is normally used to add encryption to a server that doesn't do encryption.  in this case it's the client that can't encrypt.

Comment: Yes, this way the client will connect to the stunnel, which will then connect through SSL to the POP3S server.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks, this solved a big problem for me. FYI: Also had to set client = yes.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`perdition`](http://www.vergenet.net/linux/perdition/) - you can use it to gateway POP3 and IMAP servers.

You'd need to run it somewhere, and point your CRM system at that, and then perdition would talk to the real SSL encrypted POP3 service.

It should cope quite happily with a clear channel between you and itself, and an encrypted channel between itself and the real server.